# What are the other heroku environment variables?

Tags: web-services, heroku, environment-variables

When setting up a server, I noticed that the environment variable process.env.PORT is used. Are there any other variables like this? Where can I see all of them?

Comment: `heroku run printenv`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why no selected answer on this one?

Answer (score 113):

The following command will display *all* of the environment variables, not just those visible from `heroku config`:

```
heroku run printenv
```

Comment: Pipping it with `sort` would be a better solution: `heroku run printenv | sort`

Comment: If the environment variable is specific to dyno size (I tried this to check what my `WEB_CONCURRENCY` was and was confused by the results at first), then it's important to match your dyno size with what you're going to use: `heroku run -s performance-L printenv` for a performance-L dyno.

Comment: @EduardoSantana be careful sorting your envvars using `| sort`: any multi-line envvars will lead to highly confusing output.

Comment: I haven't been on Heroku for years... They have multi-line ENV vars now? 

Answer (score 14):

`heroku config` does not show PORT.  So, it's incomplete if you need *everything*.  This will create a one-off dyno and show everything.

From here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#console

Run a console in a one-off dyno, then at the > prompt, type "console.log(process.env)":

```
$ heroku run node
Running `node` attached to terminal... up, run.4778
> console.log(process.env
... )
{ BUILDPACK_URL: 'https://github.com/MichaelJCole/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git#wintersmith',
  TERM: 'xterm',
  SENDGRID_USERNAME: 'unicorns@heroku.com',
  COLUMNS: '80',
  DYNO: 'run.4778',
  PATH: '/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin:bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin',
  PWD: '/app',
  PS1: 'fairydust',
  LINES: '22',
  SHLVL: '1',
  HOME: '/app',
  SENDGRID_PASSWORD: 'ponies',
  PORT: '52031',
  _: '/app/bin/node' }
undefined
```

Answer (score 9):

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars: there's a command that appears to tell you what your environment variables are.

```
$ heroku config
```

See if that works for you.

EDIT: it appears the heroku docs linked above are wrong. Try this:

```
$ heroku config -s --app <appname>
```

Answer (score 9):

The command is

```
heroku config
```

You can read more here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: This is a good answer, but misses some env variables like PORT.  See below if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are 100% of my environment variables for a working Node.JS app.**

The documentation on heroku is pretty shitty for this.
You'd expect they'd have something like what google
app engine reference has:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime

But, since they don't , my solution was just to create
a simple "rest" endpoint that logs out all of the
environment variables. Don't do this in a serious application.
Instead I'd use "Michael Cole" 's logging method.

Please don't hack me. This project won't exist after November 2022 because heroku will no longer be free. So I'll risk it. Currently porting my code to "GoogleAppEngine".

```
HEROKU_EXEC_URL : 
    https://exec-manager.heroku.com/370aa52e-ced2-4ad1-9db7-b11f98f8a7fd

DATABASE_URL ::::
    postgres://amrspwutkevecg:4958212525b67f2ee7a0f49c0c465f65da4c3e352880f5999f8ea6fac63a4cf5@ec2-34-200-35-222.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/ddb2djh5t66gqj

npm_config_user_agent :
    npm/8.19.2 node/v16.18.0 linux x64 workspaces/false

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS :  
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true 
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.17.42.66 
    -Djava.rmi.server.port=1099

npm_node_execpath :
    /app/.heroku/node/bin/node

SHLVL : 0
npm_config_noproxy : <EMPTY STRING>
PORT : 19842
HOME : /app
npm_package_json : /app/package.json
PS1  : \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;32m\]$ \[\033[00m\]
npm_config_userconfig : /app/.npmrc
npm_config_local_prefix : /app
COLOR : 0
npm_config_metrics_registry : https://registry.npmjs.org/
_ : /app/.heroku/node/bin/npm
npm_config_prefix : /app/.heroku/node
WEB_CONCURRENCY : 1
npm_config_cache : /app/.npm
npm_config_node_gyp : /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
PATH : /app/node_modules/.bin:/node_modules/.bin
     :/app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/node-gyp-bin
     :/app/.heroku/node/bin
     :/app/.heroku/yarn/bin
     :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
     :/bin:/app/bin:/app/node_modules/.bin
NODE :/app/.heroku/node/bin/node
MEMORY_AVAILABLE : 512
NODE_HOME : /app/.heroku/node
HEROKU_JMX_OPTIONS : 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true 
    -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.17.42.66 
    -Djava.rmi.server.port=1099

HEROKU_APP_ID : 265115d9-6eb1-4352-a83c-05b844ece512

npm_lifecycle_script : node ./ATOMIC_IVY_MMO.JS
npm_lifecycle_event  : start
npm_config_globalconfig : /app/.heroku/node/etc/npmrc
npm_config_init_module : /app/.npm-init.js
PWD : /app
npm_execpath : /app/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm_config_global_prefix : /app/.heroku/node
npm_command : start
NODE_ENV : production
WEB_MEMORY : 512
DYNO : web.1
INIT_CWD : /app
EDITOR : vi
```

**Environment variables added after running :**

```
heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata -a <app name>
```

Are **non-standard** , but can be useful. Especially "**HEROKU_APP_NAME**"
which you can use to allow your client-side app to make XMLHTTPRequests
to your server's API.

```
HEROKU_APP_ID              unique identifier for the application.   
                           "9daa2797-e49b-4624-932f-ec3f9688e3da"
HEROKU_APP_NAME            application name.                        
                           "example-app"
HEROKU_DYNO_ID             dyno identifier. This metadata is not yet available in Private Spaces nor the Container Registry.    
                           "1vac4117-c29f-4312-521e-ba4d8638c1ac"
HEROKU_RELEASE_CREATED_AT  time and date the release was created.       
                           "2015-04-02T18:00:42Z"
HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION     identifier for the current release.  
                           "v42"
HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT         commit hash for the current release.     
                           "2c3a0b24069af49b3de35b8e8c26765c1dba9ff0"
HEROKU_SLUG_DESCRIPTION    description of the current release. 
                           "Deploy 2c3a0b2"
```

Documentation for runtime medata data :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata