# Paperclip S3 issue, no method match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Been trying to integrate S3 into my paperclip class.
Did so successfully on my local and a coworker's, but it's not working on production.

Here's my image class's paperclip code:

```
has_attached_file :image,
storage: :s3,
:path  => ":imageable_type/:imageable_id/:filename",
s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV["AWS_KEY"],
      secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET"],
      bucket: ENV["S3_BUCKET"]
},
s3_region: ENV["S3_REGION"]
```

I'm getting the following error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass):`. A quick search shows it to be related to the `s3_region` not being mentioned.
It works in my development server and they the `s3_region` is included in my configurations.

I have defined the interpolations and environment variables. The environment variables are working in the rails console so that's not an issue I guess.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

what are you using to deploy to production?

For example, if you use Heroku, you need to mantain separately the `env` variables in your production server. You can do this via dashboard or the terminal

[What are the other heroku environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185353/what-are-the-other-heroku-environment-variables#28657555)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

If you use AWS then read here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

For docker read here

https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/

The env variables are defined in files like `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` of every ubuntu server/container you are running

Read more about environment variable and how to configure them