# How to print environment variables on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

I'd like to print all environment variables set on my Heroku server. How can I do that with command line only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the other heroku environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185353/what-are-the-other-heroku-environment-variables)

Answer (score 31):

Ok, I found the way:

```
heroku config
```

Comment: AFAICT this is not actually "all environment variables". Just those set via the config mechanism.

Comment: Hm, I didn't know. So, could you share how to print actually all of them?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry! I came here trying to find out!

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted solution but one of the ones below

Answer (score 15):

The `heroku run` command runs a one-off process inside a Heroku [dyno](https://www.heroku.com/dynos). The unix command that prints environment variables is `printenv` ([manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printenv.1.html)). Thus

```
heroku run -a app-name printenv
```

is the command you are looking for.

Comment: I wanted to confirm one-off commands were receiving environment parameters from  the command line, so this one was useful: `heroku run -a appname --env FOO=bar printenv`

Comment: I did run only the command `printenv` in the _web console_ (More -> Run console) and all environment variables were listed.

Answer (score 5):

### step 1 : list your apps

```
heroku apps
```

Copy the name of your app

### step 2 : view config variables of this app

```
heroku config -a acme-web
```

Answer (score 2):

Append `--json` to get the output as JSON.

```
heroku config -a acme-web --json
```

Answer (score 1):

Append `-s` to get the output in shell format, to paste directly to a `.env` file, for example.

```bash
heroku config -a your-app -s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all environment variables and not just the config you can use:

`heroku run env -a [app-name]`